# Styling the arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am quite unexperienced with using Tikz, but I want to use if for my thesis. The last two days, I have been looking over this forum for a way to adjust the thinkness of my arrows, but unfortunately this seemed to be nearly impossible in combination with the structure I am currently having.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\tikzstyle{place}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{transition}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{customer}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{depot}=[draw]
\begin{document}

\textbf{Initial Situation}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [customer/.style={circle,draw=black!100,fill=gray!50, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2mm},
depot/.style={rectangle,draw=black!100,fill=black!100,thick, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3mm}]
\node[customer] (1) at (0.1,0.1) {};
\node[customer] (2) at (0.4,2.6) {};
\node[customer] (3) at (0.7,1.2) {};
\node[customer] (4) at (1.1,1.6) {};
\node[customer] (5) at (1.3,0.3) {};
\node[customer] (6) at (1.6,2.7) {};
\node[customer] (7) at (2.2,0.8){};
\node[customer] (8) at (2.4,2.2) {};
\node[customer] (9) at (2.6,0.1) {};
\node[customer] (10) at(2.9,1.2) {};
\node[depot] (D) at (1.7,1.5) {};

% Route 1
\draw [->] (D) -- (8);
\draw [->] (8) -- (6);
\draw [->] (6) -- (2);
\draw [->] (2) -- (4);
\draw [->] (4) -- (D);

% Route 2
\draw [->] (D) -- (10);
\draw [->] (10) -- (7);
\draw [->] (7) -- (5);
\draw [->] (5) -- (3);
\draw [->] (3) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}}
```

Is there any easy quick comment  I can adjust the thickness of my arrows with? I want the line to be thicker, but especially the hat!

Looking forward to some inputs!

Comment: ,@StudentNL - You can just add the option for arrow tips at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` environment like this: `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, line cap=round] . . .`

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. So is `arrows`. What hat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: thicker arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    customer/.style={circle, draw, fill=gray!50, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm},
    depot/.style={draw, fill, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm},
    thick,
    >={Triangle[width=.75ex, length=1ex]}
  ]
  \node[customer] (1) at (0.1,0.1) {};
  \node[customer] (2) at (0.4,2.6) {};
  \node[customer] (3) at (0.7,1.2) {};
  \node[customer] (4) at (1.1,1.6) {};
  \node[customer] (5) at (1.3,0.3) {};
  \node[customer] (6) at (1.6,2.7) {};
  \node[customer] (7) at (2.2,0.8){};
  \node[customer] (8) at (2.4,2.2) {};
  \node[customer] (9) at (2.6,0.1) {};
  \node[customer] (10) at(2.9,1.2) {};
  \node[depot] (D) at (1.7,1.5) {};

  % Route 1
  \draw [->] (D) -- (8);
  \draw [->] (8) -- (6);
  \draw [->] (6) -- (2);
  \draw [->] (2) -- (4);
  \draw [->] (4) -- (D);

  % Route 2
  \draw [->] (D) -- (10);
  \draw [->] (10) -- (7);
  \draw [->] (7) -- (5);
  \draw [->] (5) -- (3);
  \draw [->] (3) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that `arrows` is deprecated, along with `\tikzstyle`. `arrows.meta` and `\tikzset` are currently recommended.

Comment: What does ` >=` mess with?

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't 'mess with' anything. It changes the style of the default arrow tip.

Comment: @cfr Thank you! I'm trying to put them in subfigures now, but for some reason he does not accept 'subfigure' and keeps on saying that I am either missing } or and \endgroup, while I have copied the structure from the forum here. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @StudentNL That sounds like a different question, so I suggest asking it as a new question. It is impossible to guess what's wrong without seeing a minimal example. The chances are good that you are missing a `}`, although the certainty is by no means 100%. Impossible to tell without the context.

Comment: @cfr that  was what I meant, it wasn't used directly in the code, thus must be messing with something I do not know about. Now I do, thanks, I needed that for another project

Comment: @daleif Oh. Well 'mess with' means to me 'screws up'. Since the point of the question was how to change the arrows, it seemed odd to describe my code as 'messing with' them. But, obviously, you might not like the particular way it changes them, in which case you might well put it that way. (Or it might mean something different in your dialect.)

Comment: @cfr I was actually looking for how to generally change the arrow heads through out an entire document, never seen that key begore

Comment: @daleif There's quite a useful section on it in the TikZ manual: section 16 'Arrows' which probably tells you everything you never wanted to know about them and then some ;).

Comment: I think I know about it, just missed the key to generally change the arrow head

Comment: @daleif There are other ways, too. I think you can also use `.tip` etc. `>` is shorthand, as I understand it.